# Javascript remove one html tag with a specific structure

Tags: javascript

I can remove all html tags from the text but I cannot remove just the structure in span tags with data-word inside ...

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}
```

Original is:

```
I <span data-word="word1" class="synonyms" title="word2">word3</span> <b>word4<b>.
```

The result should be:

```
I word3 <b>word4</b>.
```

With the script from above the result I get is:I word3 word4. So the remaining html is not preserved.

It is code from [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript).

Comment: That should be `</b>` not `<b>`.

Comment: So you want to only remove `span` tags that have a `data-word` attribute (and replace them by their content)?

Comment: Yes just this and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the elements you want to remove, replace them by their inner HTML and take the inner HTML.

```js
function stripDataWordTags(container) {
  var node = container.cloneNode(true);
  Array.prototype.slice.call(node.getElementsByClassName("synonyms"))
    .forEach(function(a, i) {
      a.parentElement.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(a.innerHTML), a);
      a.parentElement.removeChild(a);
    });
  return node.innerHTML;
}

// Demo and usage:
alert(stripDataWordTags(document.getElementById("test")));
```

```html
<div id="test">
  I <span data-word="test" class="synonyms">love</span> <b>ECMAScript 5</b>.
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, the word1 is not the same and the class is  (class="synonyms").  So this doesn't work in majority of cases.

Comment: @Brana Not sure what you mean… it doesn’t depend on the content of the attribute. If you want to select it by `class` `synonyms`, _then say so in your question_. You can easily change the selector to whatever you want, although for classes you can use `getElementsByTagName` instead of `querySelectorAll`, as the browser support for the prior is better.

Comment: The oputput with this code is the same as input - I <span data-word="test" class="synonyms">love</span> <b>ECMAScript 5</b> ... please check it.

Comment: @Brana Oh, `getElementsByTagName` should be `getElementsByClassName`. It works now, anyway.

Comment: It works but it removes just first instance of the class. For example if I have 2 sentences as in example it removes just from the first one. Yes, I didn't say i want multiple items removed, because i though this was oobvious but now i realise it isn't :)

Comment: @Brana Alright, _now_ it really works! I thought, it would already work with multiple elements, but I know why it failed: I used `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is a _live_ element collection. The first `forEach` call removes the first occurrence, the second call can’t be executed, because there is no _second_ element anymore. `slice`-ing the `HTMLCollection` first, works. `querySelectorAll` however returns a `NodeList` which doesn’t have that problem, so it even works without the `slice`.

Comment: Yes, works great. I suspected something like slice is needed. Thanks very much.